# Search box inside a div. Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, search

In my django app I display a list of elements (friends name) thanks to a loop:

```
<div>
{% for friend in group %}
    <p>{{ friend.name }} <p>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I would like to create a search box on the top of my list in order to be able to find only the friends the user wants, without refreshing the page. 
And I would like the search bar does not need to click to send the request (an example is the Airtime searchbox on top of the facebook friends list).

I have absolutely no idea on how to do that, and I'm looking for hints or tips to start.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: jQuery (or any similiar Ajax library) is your friend. Google is your friend, too.

Comment: Indeed, JQuery would do the work, I have something similar and I used Twitter bootstrap for the searchbox and JQuery to handle the behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, it's pretty easy with jQuery. Here is a straight forward example:

#### HTML

```
<input id="searchbox" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
<ul id="friendlist">
    <li>Bob</li>
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Peter</li>
    <li>Paul</li>
    <li>Adam</li>
</ul>
```

#### JavaScript

```
// case insensitive ':contains' selector
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) {
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

$(function() {
    $('#searchbox').on('keyup', function() {
        var w = $(this).val();
        if (w) {
            $('#friendlist li').hide();
            $('#friendlist li:Contains('+w+')').show();
        } else {
            $('#friendlist li').show();                  
        }
    });
});​
```

We need to define the case insensitive :Contains selector since jQuery's built-in :contains is case sensitive and that's probably not what you want.

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UH6mN/).

As a web developer you should definitely take a closer look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). You always need it.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. I just have a little problem. I opened a new topic for it, if you wan't to have a look, you could probably help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332867/getting-an-html-file-through-a-jquery-get-function-django     Thank you again, you helped me a lot!