# Getting an html file through a jquery get function. Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

In my django app I display the user facebook friends list. In order to refresh it every 10 minutes, I put this list in an other view and html, and I used a get request to get it and display it on the page I wan't.

Here is the get_fb_friends.html file where I have the friends list: (this the html file I associated to a view I created. This is where I get the list I wan't to display on the page I show to the user):

```
   {% for friend in group %}
    <li>{{ friend.name }} </li>
   {% endfor %}
```

And how I import it in my template: (this is the page where I wan't to display the list for the user).

```
JS:
     setInterval(function(){
        $.get('/mysite/get_fb_friends/', function(data) {
        $('.get_fb_friends').html(data);
    });
    }, 600000);

    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

   $(function() {
   $('#searchbox').on('keyup', function() {
    var w = $(this).val();
   if (w) {
    $('#friendlist li').hide();
    $('#friendlist li:Contains('+w+')').show();
  } else {
    $('#friendlist li').show();                  
 }
 });
 });



 HTML:

     <div class='get_fb_friends'> </div>
```

Then, I wan't to include a search bar on top of this list, in order the user to be able to search the friends he wants. So in my get_fb_friends.html, I added:

```
  HTML:
    <input id="searchbox" type="text" placeholder="Search" />    
    <ul id="friendlist">
    {% for friend in group %}
    <li>{{ friend.name }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

This search bar works perfectly if I use it on the page www.mysite/get_fb_friends, but not anymore once it's get by the jquery get request (i.e on the page where I wan't to display it for the user); I type one letter and all the names disappear.

It looks like when I get the html file through the jquery get function, it does not keep the 'li' I need in my jquery function.

Any idea on what is happening?

I hope my question is clear, thank you for your help.

EDIT:

My main page:

```
 HTML:
 <div class="friendlist" id="friendlist"> 


 JS:

 $.get('/mysite/get_fb_friends/', function(data) {
    $('.friendlist').html($(data).find($('#friendlist').html()));
    });

 return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };

   $(function() {
    $('#searchbox').on('keyup', function() {
      var w = $(this).val();
       if (w) {
        $('#friendlist li').hide();
        $('#friendlist li:Contains('+w+')').show();
      } else {
        $('#friendlist li').show();                  
     }
     });
     });
```

My remote page:

```
 HTML:
 <input id="searchbox" type="text" placeholder="Search" />    
 <ul id="friendlist" class="friendlist">

  {% for friend in group %}
    <li>{{ friend.name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: it is confusing as to what html/js is in what file and in what order. Can simplify `$.get` even more to `$('.get_fb_friends').load('/mysite/get_fb_friends/');` but that won't resolve any other issues

Comment: Ok, thank you for the tip. I edited my question in order to make it clearer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you really only want to update the list content, and not replace the `input` and full list itself with every refresh.

In that case you would want all the JS in main page , change your output of remote file to simply sending back `LI` tags and inserting them into new target `friendlist`. This insert could be a full replacement, or only appending new found names. Not sure how your app is intended to work with this regard

You could also add a flag not to make the ajax call is user is doing any filtering with the input.

Flag could be something like

```
$('#searchbox').on('focus blur', function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('active')
})
```

Then in the `setInterval`

```
setInterval(function(){
        if( ! $('#searchbox').hasClass('filter') ){
            $('#friendlist').load('/mysite/get_fb_friends/')
       }
    }, 600000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need a full replacement, because I sort the friends depending on their activity (active, idle or offline). So if I get what you said, I have to put the search bar (html and JS) in the main page. then I need to change my jquery get request in order to get only the LI tags. But I have to admit I don't know how to ask the get request to get only that. Could you give me a hint, or a good tuto about jquery get function? Thanks!

Comment: can you change the output of the remote page to only send the LI tags? If not the remote page can be parsed in the ajax success in main page

Comment: also just noticed  `$('#friendlist').hide();` should likely be `$('#friendlist li').hide();` and could be root cause of not seeing anything at all. You are hiding the parent and you can't display children of a hidden parent any time

Comment: I really don't know how i could only send the LI tags. Could you help me on that?

Comment: OK can do this `$.get('/mysite/get_fb_friends/', function(data) {
        $('#friendlist').html($(data).find( $('#friendlist').html());
    });` This will parse the returned page and only pull out the LI tags and replace them in main page

Comment: Ok thank you a lot, but when I do that the get function does not work anymore. I used your function, tried to render it this way <div class="friendlist">, but it does not work...

Comment: I'm developing locally. But I edited my question to show you exactly what I did.

Comment: can you move `$('#searchbox').on()` to main?

Comment: Still doesn't work. I edited to show you. The thing is that the get request doesn't work anymore. I can't see the list on the main page anymore...

Comment: will need to use browser console to troubleshoot. Look for errors first and can inspect the full ajax request for status, return data etc

Comment: Ok, in my console I saw the error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Contains. So I just changed the way I imported the jquery library, and now it works. The only problem is that now it's case sensitive. I don't get why.

Comment: if planning on doing any javascript at all... console in chrome or firebug in Firefox is a **huge huge huge** time saving tool